# Как отключить кнопку до тех пор пока анимация не будет законченна?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
import sys
import random
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           # <--- PySide2
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets             # <--- PyQt5

class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False
        )
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: ; }")
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)
        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)
        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.toggle_button.setObjectName(u"click_me")

        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )
    #@QtCore.Slot()                                                     # <--- PySide2
    #@QtCore.pyqtSlot()                                                 # <--- PyQt5
    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not checked
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        #self.toggle_button.setEnabled(False) #----OFF----
        self.toggle_animation.start()
        #self.toggle_button.setEnabled(True) #----ON----

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() 
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        #------layout------
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)  
        vlay.setObjectName(u"central_c_layout")
        for i in range(3):
            box = CollapsibleBox("Collapsible_Header_{}".format(i))
            vlay.addWidget(box)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            for j in range(3):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Label {}-{}".format(i, j))
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                label.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setMaximumWidth(150)
                label.setMinimumHeight(25)
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(i, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
                lay.addWidget(label)
            box.setContentLayout(lay)
        vlay.addStretch()        

StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но у меня в нем появилась проблема. 
**Если я нажимаю слишком долго мышь, то кнопка активируется до завершения анимаций, и появляется вот такой баг.**

[image: баг]

Кто нибудь знает как это поправить?

Я пытался использовать `setEnabled()`, но это у меня не особо получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправил вашу "багу". Показываю только внесенные изменения.
Проблема связана с изменением значения QToolButton.checked

В конструктор добавьте переменную, например, `self.__expand` (расширять):

```
class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)
        # ... остальной код конструктора без изменений
        # спецпеременная, ответственная за расширение/схлопывание
        self.__expand = True

    # on_pressed - целиком
    def on_pressed(self):
        # замена на __expand
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not self.__expand else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not self.__expand                   # <- замена на __expand
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        # инвертируем значение __expand
        self.__expand = not self.__expand

        self.toggle_animation.start()
```

Comment: хорошее решение - `+`

Comment: @S.Nick Благодарю!